# Is it possible to change the line style in an Excel chart according to a value in a cell?

Tags: excel, if-statement, charts, line, conditional-statements

I was wondering if it is possible to change the style of a line (e.g. its color, style, or any other property) according to the value of the cell.
Something like this:

```
data#  |  value1  | value2 | condition
1      |    3     |   5    |
2      |    5     |   7    |  true
```

Line 1 should be normal, whereas line 2 must be dashed since the fourth column says true.
Any idea? Or any workaround?

Comment: no VBA thanks, I prefer not to use it

Comment: generally before voting down one should provide at least an explanation. Is that so obvious?

Answer (score 2):

::: Ignore this - I misunderstood you need it for charts, sorry :(  :::

You can use Conditional Formatting.  Highlight a row, and go to Home --> Conditional Formatting.

Choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format", and type this in as the formula (assuming you highlighted range `A2:D2`), `=d2="True"`, then click "Format" and choose the formatting you want for the row, when `D2` is `True`.  Then, click "Ok" and edit the applicable range for the formatting (first it shows `A2:D2`, so change to say `A2:D10`.

Edit: My mistake, I didn't realize you were looking to do this for a Chart.  AFAIK you can't do conditional formatting with charts.  There's most likely a VBA solution, but there are [some sites](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/341-creating-an-excel-chart-with-conditional-formatting) that show you workarounds for using "conditional formatting" with charts.  [Here's another](https://alesandrab.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/create-charts-with-conditional-formatting/) that might help.

Comment: maybe I didn't get your answer but I don't want to format cells. I want to change the style of a line in a chart

Comment: @pnuts Nope, he misunderstood and I got two votes down for a question nobody answered, that's cool

Comment: @Nicolas - I see you prefer not to use VBA, but of course you must weigh how important the "conditional formatting" on the line is, over not using VBA.  If you don't want it because it requires users to use them on their own, and enable macros, you can always run it on *your* file, then save as `.xls` and then send to the end users?

Comment: @pnuts I know that is a site of programmers, but writing IF statements in excel cells is not programming? I don't see much difference. I think that difference between 'logic' and 'programming' is quite small...

Comment: @BruceWayne I dunno how to do what you say, since generally I don't use excel and I prefer to use other softwares but someone asked me about excel specifically.